# Calculating a norm

Tags: real-analysis

$\newcommand\norm[1]{\left\lVert#1\right\rVert}$
How can I compute $\norm{x}_p$ and $\norm{z}_p$, what will happen if $p\to \infty$? For $x=(2^{-n})_{n\in {\mathbb{N}}}$, and $z=(1,0,0,0,...)$. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you mean the $\ell^p$ norm for $p\in[1,\infty)$. We can do both sequences using the definition of $\|\cdot\|_p$. First, let's try $z$:
$$\|z\|_p^p=\sum_{n\in\mathbb{N}} |z_n|^p = 1^p = 1, \quad \text{so } \|z\|_p=1 \; \text{for all } p.$$
So we get $\lim_{p\to\infty}\|z\|_p =1$. Now consider the sequence $x=(2^{-n})_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$:
$$\|x\|_p^p = \sum_{n\in\mathbb{N}}2^{-np} = \sum_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\left(\frac{1}{2^p}\right)^n=\frac{2^p}{2^p-1}$$
The last step is valid whenever $2^p>1$, which holds for every $p\in[1,\infty)$. It is just the formula for a geometric series. We get:
$$\|x\|_p = \frac{2}{(2^p-1)^{1/p}}\to 1 \quad \text{as } p \to \infty.$$

Comment: Of course, I was talking about $l^p$ I was stuck in geometric series. Your calculation helped me solved my problem. Thank you!